# What is this small port on my laptop?

Tags: laptop, connector

I have a laptop that is a couple years old, and noticed a port on the side that I don't recognize. It is small and looks like a USB mini jack, and has a symbol next to it that looks like a computer monitor with two bars next to it.

[image]

Does anyone know what this port is, and what's it's for?

Comment: It looks like displayport. Only about 80% sure though.

Comment: @chipperyman573 Displayport is bigger, I thought. And wouldn't it have that funky "+P" logo?

Comment: I would guess, that it is bespoke to the laptop. Did the laptop come with any external devices? It looks likes a USB 2.0 Type B... Any way, telling us the make and model will help :)... Although it really does look like a VGA port!

Comment: @DaveRook No, not that I'm aware of. My first thought that it was maybe a Mini DisplayPort, but I think those are [less wide and the corners are sharper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mini_DisplayPort_on_Apple_MacBook.jpg).

Comment: Have you looked at the user manual or on the manufacturer's web site? If you give us the brand and model might help us find it.

Comment: @CharlieRB I should have looked there first. It's a Mini-VGA port.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a "guessing-game" type question. See meta.superuser.com/a/6074/23133

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it [in the manual](http://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/user_guides/u510_ug_en.pdf) (laptop is a Lenovo U510). I should have looked there first!

It is a Mini-VGA port.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a Mini-DVI port. Here is a drawing of some common display port types:

[image: Display interface connections]

[Source](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-D-dhOj-4u6Q/ToID3jxdDZI/AAAAAAAAAQI/gF-Wf9BEFqk/s1600/video-ports1.png)

Answer (score 1):

It is a mini VGA port. Even looking at the connectors you can see it could fit.